# Webfilters vs resourceservers for JWT tokens in Spring Security 5

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, azure-active-directory

My application has a SPA built with React/Redux that is interact with a Spring Boot 2 Webflux backend with Spring Security 5.

The frontend uses the implicit Oauth2 Flow to receive a access token from Azure Active Directory.

The access token is attached in frontend as a Bearer token on all request to the backend.

Up until here things have worked out find and the implementation is clear to me. However, I fail to understand what is the correct way to handle the access token in my backend controllers to do authorization.

The solution I need is to look at the claims in my access token and decide if the request is autorized to the specific endpoint.

The reason I am confused is because I see two different solutions suggested on the internet and I do not understand the different uses cases they solve or if the two solutions are for the same use case.

The solutions are:

1. Create a webfilter that validate the accesstoken and then convert it to `AbstractAuthenticationToken` using something like `.addFilterAt(bearerAuthenticationFilter(), SecurityWebFiltersOrder.AUTHENTICATION);` ([this](https://github.com/raphaelDL/spring-webflux-security-jwt))
2. Make my backend into a Oauth2 resource server and then configure `.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwtAuthenticationConverter(...)` to convert each JWT into a `AbstractAuthenticationToken`. This would validate my token and then convert it into something I can use when annotating my controller for security.

My questions now are:

Are the two solutions equal or are they for totally different use cases and is so for what use case is each solutions appropriate? Are they equal in terms of how my token is validated?

Comment: what are you sending from the client to the backend, a oauth2 token or a jwt?

Comment: Azure access token are JWT.